# Determine an interval in which the solution to the given IVP exists. Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine an interval in which the solution to the given IVP exists.
$$(x-3){dy\over dx}+(\ln x)y=2x;  (1,2)$$
I was wondering if I needed to to separation of variables or the thing where I multiply by $\mu$...
If someone could help point me in the right direction, that would be grand, thanks!

Comment: Yes to both of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

We are given:

$$\tag 1 (x-3){dy\over dx}+(\ln x)y=2x;  y(1) = 2$$

For a first-order linear DEQ, we consider the following IVP.

$$y'(x) + p(x)y(x) = g(x), y(x_0) = y_0.$$

If $p(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous functions on an open interval $\alpha \lt x \lt \beta$ and the interval contains $x_0$, then there is a unique solution to the IVP on that interval.

Some important notes:

- We may not be able to find a closed form solution, but this theorem tells us that it exists and there will be only one of them.
- If the interval in the theorem is the largest possible interval where $p(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous, then the interval is the interval of validity for the solution.
- We can find several intervals, but only one will contain $x_0$ for the problem and $y_0$ can be any value.

Lets rewrite $(1)$ in this form, yielding:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} + \dfrac{\ln x}{x-3}y(x) = \dfrac{2x}{x-3}, ~~ y(1) = 2.$$

For $p(x)$ and $g(x)$, we can see two issues.

- $(1)$ For $\ln x$, we need $x \gt 0$.
- $(2)$ For $x-3$, we need $x \ne 3$.

From these, we arrive at two intervals, $0 \lt x \lt 3$ and $3 \lt x \lt \infty$.

Finally, for this IVP, the first interval contains $x_0$ and is our interval of existence.

There is no closed form for this problem, but you can use Euler's or Runge-Kutta to numerically verify this.

Comment: Definitely deserves a TU! +1

Comment: Dr. Amy's friendly reminder: Take it easy at the gym! ;-) And...from your friend, Amy, "MTMOT"

Comment: Chores...chores...big sigh! (I've got a handful to do today, myself!)